# При выполнении "systemctl enable ..." получаю Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, service, systemd

Есть сервис для запуска приложения(запускается скрипт который запускает бинарник):

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Application unit
After=network.target
After=network-online.target
After=display-manager.service
Requires=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/test_app.pid
WorkingDirectory=/opt/test_app

Restart=always
RestartSec=3

User=root
Group=root

ExecStart=/opt/test_app/scripts/runapp.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -u root test_app_bin
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Всё делаю на следующей оси(на некоторых других ос такого нет):

```
NAME="ROSA"
VERSION="Cobalt"
ID="rels"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.3"
```

Делаю enable, получаю ошибку:

```
[root@rosa-cobalt 13:31 ~]$ systemctl enable test_app.service
Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument
```

С помощью гугла предположил что у меня проблема в секции [Install].
Не особо разбираюсь в этом. Проверил "целевой юнит по умолчанию" вроде всё совпадает.

```
[root@rosa-cobalt 13:36 ~]$ systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

Как избавится от ошибки?

Comment: что делает сервис? Нужна ли вообще графика ему?

Comment: @Sheridan Вообще приложение графическое, но служба запускает скрипт который потом запускает уже бинарник с графикой

Comment: А втупую из терминала запускается с этими же параметрами?

Comment: @donRumata /opt/test_app/scripts/runapp.sh сам скрипт, да

Answer (score 1):

Графическое приложение - не системд-сервис. При подобном запуске у него не будет доступа к xorg-server, будет запущено под другим пользователем и так далее. Если нужно запустить приложение автоматом в x-сессии, то вам нужно почитать как это сделать в выбранном вами Desktop Environment.
Например, для гнома будет [так](https://askubuntu.com/q/37957/989902), для KDE - [так](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Autostart)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, это действительно новое для меня.
Но это не то что нужно в данном вопросе, на большинстве других систем такой способ работает без нареканий.

Comment: Не встречал такого чтобы приложениями в юзерской графической сессии управлял systemd... Можете пример привести?

Comment: Может я что то не так понял, ну вот например anydesk, приложение с графикой вроде. Там тоже в процессе установки создаётся демон anydesk.service, так же стопится и перезапускается, с содержанием довольно-таки похожим на то что в описании.

Comment: скорее всего там разделение на серверную и клиентскую часть. Серверная - сервис - графики не требует и предоставляет api. Клиентская работает с этой api

Comment: Вполне может быть

Answer (score -1):

Сервис подкидывался в /lib/systemd/system/, и при выполнении systemctl enable test_app.service должна, как я потом понял, создаваться ссылка в /etc/systemd/system/.
У меня там уже была какая то ссылка с таким же именем, видимо после каких то тестов.
Я её просто удалил, теперь всё работает как часы.
Суть проблемы я так и не понял, это какой частный случай видимо.

Comment: Нет. Не стоит ни в /lib, ни в /usr... В общем то вообще никуда не стоит руками лезть кроме домов, /tmp, /opt (не трогая дистрибутивное), /etc и /usr/local. Сервис сразу ложите в /etc/systemd/system и оно его увидит.